# MySQL Stored Procedure Issue, Error 1414

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have an issue when I attempt to run this stored procedure. That it returns SQL Error 1414. I could use some help.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `date_code.GetDateCode`(IN `CalenderYear` INT, IN `DayOfYear` INT, OUT `DateCode` CHAR(2))
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ""

BEGIN
DECLARE charFirst TINYINT;
DECLARE DateCode CHAR(2);
SET DateCode = "XX";

CASE
    WHEN CalendarYear >= 2000 AND CalendarYear <= 2009 THEN
        SET charFirst = 1;
    WHEN CalendarYear >= 2010 AND CalendarYear <= 2019 THEN
        SET charFirst = 0;
    WHEN CalendarYear >= 2020 AND CalendarYear <= 2029 THEN
        SET charFirst = 1;
    WHEN CalendarYear >= 2030 AND CalendarYear <= 2039 THEN
        SET charFirst = 0;
    WHEN CalendarYear >= 2040 AND CalendarYear <= 2049 THEN
        SET charFirst = 1;
 END CASE;

 IF charFirst = 1 THEN
    SELECT CONCAT(code, fiscal_code) INTO DateCode FROM months 
    WHERE CalendarYear = calendar_year 
    AND DayOfYear >= months.fiscal_month_day_of_year_begin 
    AND DayOfYear <= months.fiscal_month_day_of_year_end;
 ELSE
   SELECT CONCAT(fiscal_code, code) INTO DateCode FROM months 
    WHERE CalendarYear = calendar_year 
    AND DayOfYear >= months.fiscal_month_day_of_year_begin 
    AND DayOfYear <= months.fiscal_month_day_of_year_end;
 END IF;
END
```

Here is a copy of my table ...

[image: Database Table]
I need to know how to call this stored procedure from the mysql command prompt. I have tried ...

```
SET @dc = "XX";
CALL `date_code.GetDateCode`(2016, 14, @dc);
```

This returns SQL Error 1414. Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you call the procedure without the ``: CALL date_code.GetDateCode(2016, 14, @dc);

Comment: Without `` I get SQL Error (1305): PROCEDURE date_code.GetDateCode does not exist

Comment: Just got a new error `MariaDB [date_code]> CALL `date_code.GetDateCode`(2016,14,@dc);
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'CalendarYear' in 'field list'
MariaDB [date_code]>`

Comment: That sounds better: A procedure is not checked if it can run all its queries etc. So check the field list of your queries to see if CalendarYear is present everywhere

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, isn't it defined in the create procedure code I listed above? `CREATE DEFINER=`vms_dba`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `date_code.GetDateCode`(IN `CalenderYear` INT, IN `DayOfYear` INT, OUT `DateCode` CHAR(2))`

Comment: `IN CalenderYear` != `CASE WHEN CalendarYear`, it looks like a typo. Where do you define `calendar_year`?.

Comment: calendar_year is a column in the database table. CalendarYear is an IN variable, I am a newbie so I may have missed something here.